# What is the sizeof std::array<char, N>?

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof, stdarray

What does the C++ standard say about what `sizeof(std::array<char, N>)` should be (for some constant `N`)?

In a [comment to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172879/memory-layout-2d-nm-data-as-pointer-to-nm-buffer-or-as-array-of-n-pointers-t/25173173#comment39195129_25173173), it was mentioned that `std::array` is not always "stack allocated". The comment was in response to a different comment that speculated that putting a too large of a constant for `std::array` that is declared as a local variable could cause the program to abort due to insufficient resources for the "stack allocated" variable. I assume the followup comment meant that it would be possible for `std::array` to somehow switch to a dynamic allocation mode.

I could imagine that there could be some kind of SFINAE could be applied for an array size threshold that triggers a specialization of `std::array` that actually dynamically allocates an array and manages it. In that case, the `sizeof(std::array<...>)` might just be the size of a pointer. Is that allowed to happen?

Comment: [Trying it](http://ideone.com/Y3ADE5) seems to suggest it's always `N`.

Comment: @user2357112: Yeah, I did try with g++ and clang++ and it seems to always be `N`, but that doesn't mean the standard wouldn't allow something different to happen.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) says "This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member." I think that implies the size is always N, though I don't know C++ well enough to say for certain.

Comment: @user657267: Thanks for finding that duplicate. That is pretty much exactly what I am asking, except I still don't have an explanation for what that comment meant.

Comment: @jxh : That comment meant that the array's data could be stored in a read-only memory segment, if e.g. you had `static std::array<int const, 3> const x = {1, 2, 3};`, and read-only segments won't have the size limitations that stack allocation does. Dynamic allocation is _not_ an option for `std::array<>`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Obviously `sizeof(std::array<char, N>) != N` if `N == 0`. It also doesn't necessarily hold for `N > 0`.
§23.3.2.1 [array.overview]/p1-2:

> The header `<array>` defines a class template for storing fixed-size
>   sequences of objects. An array supports random access iterators. An
>   instance of `array<T, N>` stores `N` elements of type `T`, so that
>   `size() == N` is an invariant. The elements of an array are stored
>   contiguously, meaning that if `a` is an `array<T, N>` then it obeys
>   the identity `&a[n] == &a[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < N`.
>
> An array is an
>   aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the syntax
>
> ```
> array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };
> ```
>
> where `initializer-list` is a comma-separated list of up to `N`
>   elements whose types are convertible to `T`.

§8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr]/p1:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

Since `array` is an aggregate type, it can't have a custom constructor that performs dynamic allocation, and it must store the elements directly since it must be able to be initialized from a initializer list using aggregate initialization. However, nothing in the standard prevents the implementation from adding extra stuff after its C-style array member, as long as `array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };` has the defined semantics when the *initializer-list* contains at most `N` members. An implementation that looks like

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct array {
    //typedefs and member functions omitted

    T _Elems[N];
    double _Because_I_can;
};
// specialization for N == 0 case omitted
```

is perfectly legal. Therefore, there's no guarantee that `sizeof(std::array<char, N>) == N`.