# How to find size of multidimensional std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, size, stdarray

I am having a multidimensional `std::array` and looking for the proper (convenient and efficient) way to find its *size* (in number of cells or in bytes)

`size()` returns only the last dimension size (which is understood)

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3>, 6>, 100> my_array;

my_array.size();  // returns 100
```

Although the size of the array is known in compile time, I wish to avoid `#define SIZE_OF_MY_ARRAY` or a global variable because, I am looking for a better way than passing the size with the array (as in "old" arrays, not std array), or informing others to use the defined term.

I also prefer no to calculate it every time.

Perhaps these 2 preferences are not possible for multidimensional array?

How can I efficiently find the overall size of `my_array`? I am using [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

Comment: How about `my_array.size() * my_array[0].size() * my_array[0][0].size() * my_array[0][0][0].size()`?

Comment: size in bytes is `sizeof(my_array)`, size in cells is `my_array.size()`, amount of doubles is `sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(double)`

Comment: To be honest, I don't get the problem. If you know the sizes of all arrays at compile time, why can't you simply multiply them, i.e. `size = 2 * 3 * 6 * 100;`?

Comment: Isn't the idea that `std::array` has "no hair" (no extraneous information, just like built-in arrays),  i.e. `sizeof(my_array)/sizeof(double)` yields the element count?

Comment: @vahancho I bet you because the OP looks for a solution that does not involve specific indices or number of dimensions.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I edited the question to answer some of what your wrote and for others that will find this question in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too hard to write a small utility that calculates this at compile time.

```
template<typename T> struct arr_sz {
    static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof(T);
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct arr_sz<std::array<T, N>> {
    static constexpr std::size_t size = N * arr_sz<T>::size;
};
```

The above should unravel a nested array definition of any practical depth, and evaluate to the size in bytes used for storing `T`'s, with all potential padding excluded.

An example of using it would be

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3>, 6>, 100> my_array;
constexpr auto sz = arr_sz<decltype(my_array)>::size;
static_assert(sz == sizeof(double) * 2 * 3 * 6 * 100, "");
```

That you may see [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef2b4a9d787ec015).

Comment: Is it possible that `arr_sz<decltype(my_array)>::size / sizeof(arr_sz<decltype(my_array)>::value_type)` is larger than the overall number of elements?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - Could be smaller if unsigned overflow occurred during the computation. Don't see how it could be larger.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursion to calculate its size:

```
template<typename T>
size_t get_array_full_size(T &val) { // for the last array type (double in this case)
    return 1;
}

template<typename T, size_t Len>
size_t get_array_full_size(std::array<T, Len> &arr) {
    return get_array_full_size(arr[0]) * arr.size();
}

int main() {
    std::array<std::array<std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3>, 6>, 100> my_array;
    std::cout << get_array_full_size(my_array) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. This functional approach seems similar to StoryTeller's data approach.

Answer (score 2):

**How about**

```
sizeof(my_array)/sizeof(double);
```

Comment: The question is probably whether the standard guarantees that.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider it does not apparently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173462/what-is-the-sizeof-stdarraychar-n

Answer (score 2):

Something similar to *@KorelK* 's approach. Recursive template function will stop when 
class template of `std::array` [is primitive type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental).

**([See online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LIMizMxw1XEqYUKI))**

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits> // std::is_fundamental_v

template<typename Type, std::size_t N>
std::size_t overall_size(const std::array<Type, N>&)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_fundamental_v<Type>)   return N;
    else return N * overall_size(Type{});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `constexpr` variables that bind to the dimensions and then use those to compute the desired quantity.

```
constexpr int n1 = 2;
constexpr int n2 = 3;
constexpr int n3 = 6;
constexpr int n4 = 100;

std::array<std::array<std::array<std::array<double, n1>, n2>, n3>, n4> my_array;

constexpr int myArraySize = n1*n2*n3*n4;
```

Comment: I suppose the OP wanted to extract the constants *from the array* and find a general solution which can e.g. be written as a template function which works with all `std::array`s regardless of their specific sizes or number of dimensions. Your solution would also replace the `size()` member function which is obviously useful, but works only for the last dimension.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Fair point. I think StoryTeller just posted such a solution, it's indeed superior.