# C++ Unable to copy uint8_t* to std::array<char>

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
size_t const header_length = 8;
size_t const body_size_b = 8;

ServerOpcode opc;
opc = ServerOpcode::SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE_TEST;
std::string header = std::to_string(opc);
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
auto name = builder.CreateString("Orc MONSTER");
auto accountRole = Vibranium::CreateAccountRole_Packet(builder,1,name);
builder.Finish(accountRole);
size_t size = builder.GetSize();
uint8_t *buf = builder.GetBufferPointer();

std::array<char, header_length + body_size_b> buffer{};
std::copy(header.begin(), header.end(), buffer.begin());
std::copy(std::to_string(size).begin(), std::to_string(size).end(), buffer.begin() + header_length);
std::cout << "Size of buff before memcpy" << buffer.size() << std::endl;
memcpy(&buffer+size, &buf, size);
std::cout << "Size of buff after memcpy" << buffer.size() << std::endl;
```

The output when I run this code gives me:

```
Size of buff before memcpy16
Size of buff after memcpy16
```

That means I haven't copied `buf` into `buffer`. Why is that? How can I unify `header`, `size` and `buf` all in one `std::array<char>` ?

I want to do that because I want to send them all three in specific sequence with Boost ASIO.

Comment: What makes you think that you didn't copy `buf` into `buffer`? The size of `buffer` is `header_length + body_size_b` i.e. 16 and that's exactly what you are printing

Comment: Yea but I get error when I try `size_t wholeSize = size + header_length + body_size_b;std::array<char, wholeSize> buffer{};` saying `Non-type template argument is not a constant expression`

Comment: You can't change size of std::array. It will always be the same as declared: std::array<char,SIZE>.

Comment: I don't see any calls to functions that changes a container's size, even if you used a resizable container.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I haven't, how can I change the size of it?

Comment: @VenelinVasilev You get that error because the second template argument of `std::array` has to be a constant expression, e.g. `const size_t wholeSize = ...`

Comment: Still if I do `const size_t wholeSize = size + header_length + body_size_b;` I get the same error @MikevanDyke

Comment: @VenelinVasilev `size` is not constant.

Comment: Array sizes are set at compile time and cannot be changed. You're looking for [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). I highly recommend reading the documentation and performing a few experiments to familiarize yourself with its use. C++ is unforgiving to those who don't know the details.

Comment: if I go `size_t const wholeSize = header_length + body_size_b;` it works, however if I go `size_t const wholeSize = size + header_length + body_size_b;` it fires the same error `Non-type template argument is not a constant expression` why is that ?

Comment: [I don't](https://godbolt.org/z/KcYqoM). Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: `std::vector` instead of `std::array` ? @john Can you make an answer with vector example so I can accept it ?

Comment: @VenelinVasilev The second template parameter has to be a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression), i.e. the compiler needs to know it's value at compile time. `size` is determined at runtime, which is why you cannot use it.

Comment: @MikevanDyke is then a vector a good replacement of array ?

Comment: Off topic but `std::copy(std::to_string(size).begin(), std::to_string(size).end(), ...` will result in undefined behaviour since `std::to_string` returns an `std::string` by value meaning the two iterators you pass to `std::copy` are from different containers.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know `size_t size` in advance it is best to use a vector to copy `buf` into a new buffer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

// ... 
size_t size = builder.GetSize();
uint8_t *buf = builder.GetBufferPointer();

std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
std::copy(header.begin(), header.end(), std::back_inserter(buffer))
// Don't know what you are intending with the following line
// std::copy(std::to_string(size).begin(), std::to_string(size).end(), buffer.begin() + header_length); 
std::copy(buf, buf + size, std::back_inserter(buffer));
```

`std::back_inserter` will fill up the vector with the entries of `header` and `buf` on the fly, i.e. during the copy procedure, so that you don't need to reserve memory for the vector in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` have a fixed size. period. It does not depend on how many elements you put inside.

So here you declare `std::array<char, header_length + body_size_b> buffer{};`

So you declare an array of size `header_length + body_size_b` and this size won't change, no matter what you do in the memory.

`buffer.size()` will always return `header_length + body_size_b` and in your case it is equal to 16.

If you want a container with variable size, use `std::vector`, and check the methods `push_back`, `resize`, `reserve`...

**EDIT**

It's probably something like that you want to do:

```
// Create a vector of the same size as the string header, and filled with the string header.
std::vector<char> buffer(header.begin(), header.end());

size_t buf_size = builder.GetSize();

// Resize the buffer vector so it can contain the header plus the content of buf
buffer.resize(buffer.size() + buf_size);

// Copy buf_size elements from the buf adress
std::copy(buf, buf + buf_size, buffer.begin() + buffer.size());
```

Comment: Thank you! However can you please show me how can I put `buf` into `std::vector<char> buffer{};` ?

Comment: After I declare `buffer` i do `size_t const wholeSize = size + header_length + body_size_b;buffer.resize(wholeSize);` And then I do `std::copy(header.begin(), header.end(), buffer.begin());` and `std::copy(std::to_string(size).begin(), std::to_string(size).end(), buffer.begin() + header_length);` however I don't know ho to include `buf` as the third element. How can I do that ?

Comment: What is buffer size ?

Comment: `buffer.resize(wholeSize);` or you mean what is the size of `buf` ?

Comment: I mean the size of buf, the number of chars that you want to store in a container after the header if I understand well

Comment: message sequence is. 1header2bodysize3body

Comment: Size of `buf` is `size_t size = builder.GetSize();`

Comment: `GetSize()` method on builder `Returns an `uoffset_t` with the current size of the buffer.`

Comment: check out the dit in my answer

Comment: Hah - I overwrote the wrong members in my example for you. It should be std::vector<char> destinationBuffer(size + 1, 0); std::copy(buf, buf + size, destinationBuffer.begin()); You could also just do std::vector<char> destinationBuffer(buf, buf + size); I would recommend you rename your objects for more clarity so instead of "size_t size" use something like "size_t orcSize" and instead of "uint8_t* buf" use something like "uint8_t* orcBuffer" That will help with maintenance and readability.

Comment: `std::vector::reserve` and a [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) can be handy as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the sizeof on an std::array as you can read from this answer [Is the size of std::array defined by standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103244/is-the-size-of-stdarray-defined-by-standard) or better from this one [What is the sizeof std::array<char, N>? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173462/what-is-the-sizeof-stdarraychar-n).